# Sum of a column for different values of another column

Tags: r

I have the following data frame:

```
d <- data.frame(x = c(6,6,6,17,17,17,68,68,68), w = c(4,2,1,0,5,1,0,2,7))
```

Now I want to add a new column `sw` such that

- for each `x=6`, `sw=4+2+1+0+5+1+0+2+7=22`,
- for each `x=17`, `sw=0+5+1+0+2+7=15`,
- for each `x=68`, `sw=0+2+7=9`.

That is,

```
d
   x w sw
1  6 4 22
2  6 2 22
3  6 1 22
4 17 0 15
5 17 5 15
6 17 1 15
7 68 0  9
8 68 2  9
9 68 7  9
```

For this example, I can do the following:

```
j = sum(d$w)
k = sum(d$w[d$x!=6])
l = sum(d$w[d$x==68])

d$sw <- c(rep(j,3),rep(k,3),rep(l,3))
```

But for 100 different values of `x`, I can't do such coding, even I may not know what values is `x` taking because I will generate the `x=round(rexp(1000,1/100))` .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can do this with `base R`

```
v1 <- sapply(unique(d$x), function(x) rep(sum(d$w[match(x, d$x):nrow(d)]), length(x)))
d$sw <- rep(v1, table(d$x))
```

Comment: Could you please explain how is `d$w[match(x, d$x):nrow(d)]`, particulary, `match(x, d$x):nrow(d)` working?

Comment: @Leaf `match` gives the index of first matching between the unique value looped and the whole column.  Then we get a sequence from that index to the last row of 'd' (`:nrow(d)`), subset the value of 'w' based on the index and `sum` it

Comment: Would you please tell why need to use `rep()` in the function(x)? The following code is also working: `v1 <- sapply(unique(d$x), function(x) sum(d$w[match(x, d$x):nrow(d)]));
d$sw <- rep(v1, table(d$x))

`

Comment: @Leaf It is to make sure that the elements are replicated to the length of each group

Comment: Just for future reader: don't forget to sort the dataframe according to `x`  (if it is not already sorted ).

Answer (score 2):

Another idea via base R using `Reduce` with `accumulate = TRUE` argument, i.e.

```
ind <- aggregate(w ~ x, d, length)$w #get lengths of each group
rslts <- rev(unlist(lapply(Reduce(`rbind`, rev(split(d, d$x)), accumulate = TRUE), 
                                                                 function(i) sum(i$w))))
d$sw <- rep(rslts, ind)

d
#   x w sw
#1  6 4 22
#2  6 2 22
#3  6 1 22
#4 17 0 15
#5 17 5 15
#6 17 1 15
#7 68 0  9
#8 68 2  9
#9 68 7  9
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a third base R solution that first calculates the values and then merges them to the original data.frame.

```
merge(df, within(aggregate(w ~ x, data=df, sum), sw <- rev(cumsum(rev(w))))[-2], by="x")
   x w sw
1  6 4 22
2  6 2 22
3  6 1 22
4 17 0 15
5 17 5 15
6 17 1 15
7 68 0  9
8 68 2  9
9 68 7  9
```

`aggregate(w ~ x, data=df, sum)` calculates the sum of w for each x group, Then `sw <- rev(cumsum(rev(w)))` creates the cumulative sum using two `revs` first to get the correct calculation and second to put it in the proper order. These functions are wrapped in `within` so a copy of this data.frame is returned, and `[-2]` drops the now extraneous w term calculated by `aggregate`. This aggregated data.frame is then merged onto the original data.frame.

**data**

```
df <- 
structure(list(x = c(6L, 6L, 6L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 68L, 68L, 68L
), w = c(4L, 2L, 1L, 0L, 5L, 1L, 0L, 2L, 7L)), .Names = c("x", 
"w"), row.names = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9"
), class = "data.frame")
```